# Is there an extension that will allow me to view videos in a sidebar for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video

I would like to be able to watch videos on sites like Youtube, while surfing the web at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in Windows 7?

Hit Win + Right Arrow to move your YouTube browser to the right half of the screen, then hit Ctrl + N to open a new browser, and finally hit Win + Left to move your browsing window to the left half of your screen.

Comment: No, I'm using Mac